# Data Toggle on Link not Opening Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have been struggling for the last several days with Modals for a project at work. The trigger is a link (with a glyphicon to let the user know it's a table) and I am trying to use data toggle on the link to open a modal containing a table. I can't figure out why it's not working.

The Trigger:

```html
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#tableA">
        <span id="tableA_icon" class="glyph-wrap">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
        </span>Table A
    </a>
```

The Modal:

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="tableA" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" link:aria-labelledby="tableA" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                   <h3 class="modal-title">Table A</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                Table code goes here (the table does display properly when using another method)


         </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

(Yes, my supervisor wants the modal to be printable (which I know will be another long pain in the neck), but right now I'm just focused on trying to get the darned Modal to open. I think I'm missing CSS on the footer buttons but that shouldn't be preventing the modal from opening, right?)

The CSS:

```css
    .modal {
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
      position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
      z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%; /* Full width */
      height: 100%; /* Full height */
      overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #333;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      border: 1px solid #EEE;
      width: 80%;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }

    /*Modal Header*/
    .modal-header {
      padding: 2px 16px;
      background-color: #EEE;
      color: white;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
      color: #aaa;
      float: right;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* Modal Body */
    .Modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

    /* Modal Footer */
    .Modal-footer {
      padding: 2px 16px;
      background-color: #EEE;
      color: white;
    }

    /*The Footer Print Button*/
    .print-btn{
        color: #aaa;
        /*float: right;*/
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .print-btn:hover,
    .print-btn:focus {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* The Footer Close Button */
    .close-btn {
      color: #aaa;
      /*float: right;*/
      display: inline;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close-btn:hover,
    .close-btn:focus {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake seems to be that you're not including Bootstrap in your code. When you do include it, it appears to work fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/9ugo7cvw/1/

To include it, as per the Bootstrap docs add this to your HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I think the mistake you're making is assuming that `data-toggle` as an attribute actually has a function. This is not the case as `data-toggle`, as far as I'm aware, is not part of HTML5 and is something that is added by Bootstrap. Without Bootstrap installed, `data-toggle="modal"` is simply a key-value pair where `data-toggle` is the key and `modal` is the value.

In case you're not too familiar with JSFiddle, Bootstrap and its dependencies are imported in the `Resources` tab on the left side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for a tag and include all css in header and js in footer It works..!

```
<a href="#yourmodal" data-target="#yourmodal" data-toggle="modal"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without viewing your JS code there's not really much for me to go off of. But if you just want your modal to display, you should give your span an id attribute or something to identify it. I moved your text "Table A" inside of the `span` tag instead of outside of it and gave it an id attribute. Then I added JavaScript to open the modal upon clicking the text. This is just one way to get your modal only to display.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5gx62bjw/2/

Another way is that you need to included the correct `script` tags in order for your modal to function correctly:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5gx62bjw/3/

Hopefully this helps you get on the right track